# Set react-leaflet map CRS atribute

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

In native Leaflet map, lib CRS attribute should be set as below

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    center: [-1800, 1000],
    zoom: 13,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 13,
});
```

How to do that in react-leaflet, I had tried some things but nothing successful :/

```
    <Map crs={CRS.useSimple()} center={[-1800, 1000]} zoom={13} doubleClickZoom={false} >

    </Map>
```

But there is an error that CRS is not imported.
How to import CRS?

Where do I wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I need to import CRS from native leaflet.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map} from 'react-leaflet'
import {CRS} from 'leaflet';
```

and then in **`MAP`** component

```
 <Map center={[0, 0]} zoom={2}  doubleClickZoom={false} crs={CRS.Simple}>
    ...
 </Map
```