# React-leaflet Circle component do not set radius

Tags: components, geometry, react-leaflet

I use this component like it should be used

```
<Circle center={[30, 70]} fillColor={"blue"} radius={70}  />
```

Problem is that circle look like dot no matter what is zoom level.
I must say that other components like Polygon render just normal as it should be.

Do you know what could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in map CRS attribute.

So Circle and other components were not rendered properly.

You can see how to solve CRS attribute on this link

[Set react-leaflet map CRS atribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185208/set-react-leaflet-map-crs-atribute)

Comment: What CRS you used for this purpose? I used Simple one, but I see nothing but a blue display.